# Best method of converting user input to UTF-8

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm building a PHP web application, and it works in UTF-8. The database is UTF-8, the pages are served as UTF-8 and I set the charset using a meta tag to UTF-8. Of course, with users using Internet Explorer, and copying & pasting from Microsoft Office, I somehow manage to get not UTF-8 input occasionally.

The ideal solution would be to throw an `HTTP 400 Bad Request` error, but obviously I can't do that. The next best thing is converting `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` to UTF-8. Is there anyway to see what character encoding the input is in so I can pass it off to `iconv`? If not, what's the best solution for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)  Example:

```
$utf8 = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($input), 'UTF-8', $input);
```

There's also [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) *if* you guarantee that the string is input as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Obviously can't guarantee the string is ISO-8859-1, but `mb_detect_encoding()` looks good

Answer (score 0):

In some cases using just utf8_encode or general checks are ok but you might lose some characters within the string. If you can build out a basic array/string list based on various types, this example being windows, you can salvage quite a bit more.

```
if(!mb_detect_encoding($fileContents, "UTF-8", true)){
    $checkArr = array("windows-1252", "windows-1251");
    $encodeString = '';
    foreach($checkArr as $encode){
        if(mb_check_encoding($fileContents, $encode)){
            $encodeString .= $encode.",";
        }
    }
    $encodeString = substr($encodeString, 0, -1);
    $fileContents = mb_convert_encoding($fileContents, "UTF-8", $encodeString);
}
```